# GORM mongodb mapping to existing collection structure

Tags: grails, mongodb, grails-orm

I'm new to Grails&GORM so this may be a quick question. We are currently looking at using GORMs mongo support and I am having a few issues mapping to existing collection data. I basically want to map to a hierachical object structure whereby my object "Merchant" has reference to another parent merchant. The BSON structure is fairly simple i.e.:

```
{
   name: "name",
   parent_id: ObjectId("[Object Id ref]")
}
```

In my model I attempted to map this relationship as follows:

```
class Merchant {
    ObjectId id
    String name
    Merchant parent

    static belongsTo = [parent: Merchant]
    static mappedBy = [parent: "parentId"]

    static mapping = {
        collection  "merchants"
    }
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

This resulted in the following BSON:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4ea6be91ce5f56cd49f43ab8"),
        "name" : "where will you g",
        "version" : NumberLong(1),
        "parent" : {
                "$ref" : "merchants",
                "$id" : ObjectId("4ea6be91ce5f56cd49f43ab8")
        }
}
```

This has two issues, namely:
- The name of the parent merchant field is "parent" and not "parent_id", which is required.
- The value of the parent field has additional meta infomation other than the id in i.e. $ref : "merchants".

Is there anyway I can keep our existing BSON structure and still have a rich object mapping.

Cheers, Chris.

Comment: Seems like you can solve part of the problems by giving the `parent_id` "column" a name: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#tableAndColumnNames  Also, maybe you don't want to use mappedBy or specify the collection.  Maybe that should actually be `table 'merchants'` not collection.  Not 100% sure on all of that.

Answer (score 0):

For the two issues, you need an additional mapping:

```
static mapping = {
    collection 'merchants'
    parent attr:'parent_id', reference:false
}
```

You should also drop the mappedBy block, since you only need it when there are multiple fields of the same type.

Finally, note that reference:false is the default in recent versions of the plugin (1.2+ I think). Note that 'attr' is named 'columnName' in other flavours of GORM.